# About Bootstrap example

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to html and css, so I just implementing this site
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/dashboard/
I do not want the left sidebar to disappear when I zoom in by pressing cmd + '+' or Ctrl + '+'. (I think I might want to see the desktop version of the web on the mobile screen.) Perhaps this is related to sticky in the dashboard.css file, but I do not know what to do. You can see dashboard.css and related files by viewing the source from the link above. Thank you!

Comment: Paste the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `em` unit with media query

```css
.rwd-container {
   width : 50px;
   height : 50px;
   margin : 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .rwd-container {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rwd-container"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o4s18wmL/8/

30em = base font size(16px) * 30 = 480px;

---

width 519px more than 30em(480px), media query doesn't apply to work

[image]

---

zoom font-size:110% , width 461.278px less than 30em(480px) , media query will work

[image]

---

Related:

- [zooming-squishes](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-squishes/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove sidebar's property position: fixed; and display: none; for mobile.